# Integrate with external frontend

Tags: cart, frontend, session

I'm trying, for various reasons, to use an "external" (as in non-Magento) frontend. I do want to keep the checkout process (because I want the order/shipping/invoicing functionality) in Magento, so I obviously must keep the Cart in Magento as well. However, **I can not get the "other" frontend to share the Cart with my Magento installation**.

### The custom frontend is:

- Integrated by simply including the Mage.php file (heavily inspired by [Magento-on-Angular](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Magento-on-Angular/tree/master/api/app/classes/Moa/API/Provider/Magento)) and using it's method for adding items to cart
- On the same domain (for now, localhost or 127.0.0.1)
- Working fine in isolation in both "systems" (i.e add-to-cart is actually adding to the cart in the same frontend, but not shared).
- Not given the same output from `Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getEncryptedSessionId()`
- Given the same output from `\Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()`
- Not given the same output from `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getId()`
- Using Laravel as framework

I do realize that a possible workaround would be to somehow force the getQuote()->getId() in the real Magento when passing cutomer to checkout. This does feel dirty though, and will probably cause lots of lost Carts (that's just a not educated guess though).

### Actual code (stripped down and combined from several methods)

#### Custom Frontend - add to cart

```
session_start();
\Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->start();
$product = \Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load((int) $productId);

$basket = \Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$basket->addProduct($product, 1);
$basket->save();
```

#### Custom Frontend - show cart sub total

```
session_start();
\Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->start();
$session    = \Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote      = $session->getQuote();
$items      = $quote->getAllItems();
$data       = array();

$totals     = $quote->getTotals();
$subTotal   = $totals['subtotal']->getValue();
$grandTotal = $totals['grand_total']->getValue();
```

The frontend is of course adding products that exist.

My best guess is that the fact that Laravel's bootstrap process starts the session **before** Magento comes in to play is a problem. If so, the question might be "how to "inject" a session into Magento programmatically".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By external frontend do you mean on another domain or subdomain or subdirectory? If it's the same domain you would be able to use the session like this. On another domain i think using the session will require some tricky workaround. Maybe you should create your own cart and when checking out making a complete request to magento so it generates an invoice and such. Like creating some sort of API between magento and your system. this website has a good article on that. http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

Comment: Hi. It is on the same domain. The mage.php used on custom frontend is the same mage.php used on the actual magento frontend. What i basically want is to force the session (at least CART session) to be the same session, without caring about of it it's from Laravel or Magento.

Answer (score 0):

> My best guess is that the fact that Laravel's bootstrap process starts the session before Magento comes in to play is a problem. If so, the question might be "how to "inject" a session into Magento programmatically".

Yes, and the simplest solution will be to close the Laravel session before initializing Magento:

```
\session_write_close();
\Mage::app();
```

Then Magento can open its own session (with the session name "frontend") and you don't have to do anything else.